# Laravel 4.2. Send email, remote SMTP, Windows Server R2, IIS

Tags: email, iis, laravel-4, smtp, windows-server

I just moved my Laravel 4.2. application from WAMP into IIS web server, and the email-function just stopped working - no idea why.

I use external SMTP server from a hosting service, so I didn't thought it was going to cause any problem.

My settings:

```
return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.*my-host*.se',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 587,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => "example@mail.com", 'name' => "Example name"),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => "user@host.se",

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => "********",

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,
```

I changed the auth properties above.

The error i get from Laravel.

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.my-host-name.se' did not match expected CN=`smtp.my-host.se'","file":"D:\\Dir1\\Dir2\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php","line":95}}
```

Any ideas? Should I maybe install a local SMTP service instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a SSL certificate issue between your server and the smtp email server.

I believe the issue is related to this: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544

There is a pull-request here you can try and see if that resolves the problem: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/571

Comment: Thanks! =)
Copied from the user "if-joerch" here: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544
"If you are using PHP 5.6, the error does occur because of the "SSL context options" used for the stream context in swiftmailer. IN PHP 5.6 verify_peer and verify_peer_name the default was set to TRUE, so PHP checks the SSL certificate.
You could disable the SSL check by modifying the function "_establishSocketConnection" in StreamBuffer.php.
Add these lines before stream_socket_client command:
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;"

Comment: I had the same issue using the Laravel Lumen framework. Just added those two lines informed by Tibbelit and it worked like a charm!